# keycloak redirect behind reverse proxy

Tags: jboss, keycloak

I am trying to get keycloak to run behind a kong ingress in kubernetes. The issue I am having is keycloak is adding a port it thinks it is on to the urls it is returning.
request: `auth.mydomain.com/auth`
response: `auth.mydomain.com:8443/auth/admin/master/console/`

client -> NLB:443 -> kong:8443 -> keycloak:8080

keycloak sees the requests `x-forwarded-port: 8443` that kong sets and replies with a path on port `8443`

Kong must be on 8443 now because of how it is launched in the container under the user kong and doesn't have access to the privileged ports.

I have set the configs keycloak suggests,

```
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding=proxy-https:add(port=443)
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=default:write-attribute(name=redirect-socket, value=proxy-https)
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=default:write-attribute(name=proxy-address-forwarding, value=true)
```

But these look like they tell undertow to reply with 443 if the request comes in in plain text, my `x-forwarded-proto: https` is set correctly.

It is also possible that the issue is the `host` header instead.

```
----------------------------REQUEST---------------------------
               URI=/auth/admin/
 characterEncoding=null
     contentLength=-1
       contentType=null
            header=X-Real-IP=<REDACTED>
            header=Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
            header=Accept-Language=en-us
            header=Accept-Encoding=br, gzip, deflate
            header=User-Agent=<REDACTED>
            header=Connection=keep-alive
            header=X-Forwarded-Proto=https
            header=X-Forwarded-Port=8443
            header=X-Forwarded-For=<REDACTED>
            header=Referer=https://auth.my-domain.com/auth/
            header=Host=auth.my-domain.com:8443
            header=X-Forwarded-Host=auth.my-domain.com
            locale=[en_US]
            method=GET
          protocol=HTTP/1.1
       queryString=
        remoteAddr=/<REDACTED>
        remoteHost=<REDACTED>
            scheme=https
              host=auth.my-domain.com:8443
        serverPort=8443
          isSecure=true
--------------------------RESPONSE--------------------------
     contentLength=0
       contentType=null
            header=Connection=keep-alive
            header=Location=https://auth.my-domain.com:8443/auth/admin/master/console/
            header=Content-Length=0
            header=Date=Fri, 21 Jun 2019 07:05:28 GMT
            status=302
```

It would be great if I could get keycloak to respond with just a path and not a port, or if it has to respond with a port, just tell it what port I want it to talk on.

Comment: Ok, more info, it is the `header=Host=auth.my-domain.com:8443` that is the issue. If anyone knows how to get wildfly to drop the port or use the `X-Forwarded-Host` that will save me hours of reading though code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `hostname` SPI which allows you to set hostname and port for `Keycloak` instead of retrieving them from HTTP request. You can set ports to default ones (80/443) and resulting URLs will not have a port displayed.

```
# Replace `request` provider with `fixed`
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=hostname:write-attribute(name=default-provider,value=fixed)
# Set hostname and ports for http and https
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=hostname/provider=fixed:write-attribute(name=properties.hostname,value=example.org)
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=hostname/provider=fixed:write-attribute(name=properties.httpsPort,value=443)
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=hostname/provider=fixed:write-attribute(name=properties.httpPort,value=80)
```

These values are not runtime configurable thus you have to restart Keycloak after the changes.

Comment: where to configure them?