# Keycloak - cannot get callbacks with HTTPS

Tags: openid, keycloak

I was digging through documentation for over an hour and cannot find it.

Due to e.g. Facebook requirements, callback uri has to use https.
I did set up https on localhost and it is working, but keycloak keep using `http` in all url config, so I cannot get it working with Facebook as provider, or even login through https to keycloak due to wrong redirect uris.

What to do to make Keycloak use HTTPS on all callbacks when being used behind the reverse proxy which is handling SSL?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56709461/keycloak-redirect-behind-reverse-proxy/56741771#56741771

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I solved it by adding `setHTTPS.cli` script which is:

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=default: write-attribute(name=proxy-address-forwarding, value=${env.PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING:false})
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https: write-attribute(name=proxy-address-forwarding, value=${env.PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING:false})
```

and setting `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING` to true. Of course the best is to also add redirection to HTTPS in proxy as if you will use HTTP, callbacks will still be HTTP