# Keycloak Admin REST API: Use client root url in e-mail body when performing execute-actions-email

Tags: java, docker, keycloak

My question is: In the Keycloak Admin REST API, when performing an email action such as *execute-actions-email* how can I make sure the URL used in the emails use a specific hostname.

Situation:

- Keycloak runs in Docker and is publicly available at https://somehost.test/auth. Within Docker http://keycloak is used as URL
- Another container uses the Java Admin Client (which uses the REST API) to request data and perform changes. The URL used is the internal URL and this works fine.
- Only when requesting an e-mail to be sent, the link ALWAYS displays the url which has been used by the API client even though it cannot be accessed by a normal user.

What I want:

- The url should be changed to the external url, which has been configured as root url for the client in Keycloak.

What I tried:

- Providing the client ID to the call, which did not help at all.
- Modifying the email template (keycloak/themes/base/email/text/executeActions.ftl), but it generates the message and I can't do much with that.
- Set up a custom RestEasyClient which set the headers (does not help)

```java
requestContext.getHeaders().add("X-Forwarded-For", "http://test.test.test");
requestContext.getHeaders().add("X-Forwarded-Host", "http://test.test.test");
requestContext.getHeaders().add("Host", "http://test.test.test");
```

No matter what, the url the users receive in their email is *http://keycloak*. If I change the url which the Java Admin Client uses to contact the rest API, the url in the email changes too. This works on my local environment but the policy on the production environment does not allow that for security reasons. I have no power to change that policy.

I read that I can create a custom endpoint for the Admin REST API. I'd rather avoid that if possible, because this will mean I have to reinvent the wheel.

I hope any of you can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can hardcode Keycloak URL in the configuration. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56709461/keycloak-redirect-behind-reverse-proxy/56741771#56741771

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It would be great if this works out so I'll try it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Vadim Ashikhman posted a comment and not an answer, I cannot mark his answer as "the answer".

His solution was not the exact solution I used but certainly pointed me in the right direction. Since my keycloak server uses the standalone(-ha).xml, I had to change it. See the [Keycloak documentation](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/7.x/server_admin/topics/threat/host.adoc#fixed-provider) for more details. It does the exact same thing but in another way.

Thanks Vadim for pointing me in the right direction and solveMe for responding.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how exactly did you fixed this? I'm facing the same problem and the docs you've linked aren't exactly explicit.

I'm running Keycloak in docker and when I use executeActions API endpoint, the address embedded in the actions link is internal docker rather than the public one.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Xaralis, I had to look it up because it had been quite a while since I implemented it. I realise the Github documentation is set to master, and they removed most of it, so I'll link to the 7.x version after I typed this message.
What I did is create a shell script, called by my Dockerfile (which extends jboss/keycloak). The shell script replaces the default provider in the standalone-ha.xml with a fixed default provider. The 7.x documentation provides the parameters which should be changed. It's strange why they removed the documentation because it still works after updating Keycloak.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i remember this email is sent from Admin Console. Yes url in email always use Account application base url, so your only way is to implement Rest endpoint SPI for sending email, and customize URL calculation. And to be able to utilize this from Admin Console, you should also add required widgets in Admin Console (see `KEYCLOAK_HOME/themes/base/admin`).

[Keycloak customization docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/server_development/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll try using Vadim's solution first as I hoped there would be another solution than creating a custom endpoint. :)

Comment: Oh yea, i forgot about hostname SPI. We still on 3.4.3, so there is no such feature.